# Anime like Slayers where the "evil guy" has one of the main characters trapped inside ice with some kind of magic

Tags: story-identification, anime

TV anime show I saw like **15 years ago**, I think it could be [*Slayers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slayers). I saw this series in Spain (and in Spanish, my mother tongue). Episodes were broadcast one each morning.

I only remember some short scenes.

- A child stole something (a small bag, I believe) from the main characters (I think) and ran away among the crowd. This boy could be poorly dressed.
- Later on in the same episode, some *evil guy* has one of the main characters **trapped inside ice** with some kind of magic and the other(s) go to save her. If I remember correctly, this *evil guy* is more powerful than they initially think, but this can be just my guess..
- Again, if I'm not wrong, the child and the *evil guy* worked together, the child gave the stolen item to him.
- All characters were white, I'd swear the character trapped inside ice was the main feminine character.
- The *evil guy* was a man, more on the thin side, and he was wearing a cape (could be similar to Dr. Strange one, high collared cape)
- Definitely, characters don't wear modern clothes nor school uniforms, but I think they have their own custom *outfit*, similar to nothing

Comment: These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Thanks @Valorum. I have read the first one, but no the second. I'll try to complete te question, but it's hard, I really can't remember so much about it. This is one of those memories you have, but just like a couple of photographs in your mind.

Comment: Hmm read through the [episode list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Slayers_episodes) and see if any of those stick out to you. There does seem to be an episode where someone is trapped in ice, but it is a male.

Comment: @Sensoray Thanks, I've watched Slayers Next episode 4 *"An Ancient Pledge! One Who Seeks Immortality!"*, where an ice cage is mentioned, but that's not the one I'm looking for.

Comment: hmm do you remember anything about their style of dress besides the cape guy? For example, did they appear to be in armor, or were they wearing modern clothing (jeans/shirt), or a school uniform? anything helps

Comment: @Sensoray I extend my question